# SQL: Case in Select use value in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a SQL command that in the SELECT there is a case that uses a value from a table or just uses '0'.

I want to use that 'cased' value in the where clause later but it's not working as I want.

Here's what I mean:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    hi.SKUNo [HostSKU] ,
    SUBSTRING(vi.GTIN, 3, 14) [GTIN] ,
    CASE vg.VendorGroup
      WHEN vg.VendorGroup THEN vg.VendorGroup
      ELSE v.VendorNo
    END [VendorNo] ,
    'Inv_Full_Sync' [Reason Code] ,
    'Vendor Inventory Full Sync' [Reason Text] ,
    CASE vi.EncodeData
      WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
      ELSE 0
    END [Quantity] , --< quantity
    'ONHAND' [OnHand] ,
    RTRIM(v.Category) [Vendor Category]
FROM    ItemInventory ii
    INNER JOIN HostItems hi ON hi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
    INNER JOIN VendorItems vi ON vi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
                                 AND vi.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
    INNER JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
    LEFT JOIN dbo.VendorGroups vg ON vg.VendorNo = v.VendorNo
WHERE   QtyType = 0
    AND [Quantity] > 0 --< here is where it bombs..
ORDER BY VendorNo ,
    hi.SKUNo;
```

Comment: You cannot use a alias you gave for a select column in the where statement itself. Instead use vi.EncodedData <> 'Y' AND ii.Quantity1 > 0 as anything other than Y would cause that field to be 0

Answer (score 1):

The alias is only applied at the end of the query's execution - you can't use it in the `where` clause. You could, however, just use the same expression:

```
WHERE QtyType = 0 AND
      CASE vi.EncodeData
         WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
         ELSE 0
      END > 0
```

Or, alternatively, just unwrap it and create a condition that relates to the underlying columns:

```
WHERE QtyType = 0 AND
      vi.EncodeData = 'Y' AND 
      ii.Quantity1 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL (in general) does not allow the use of column aliases in subsequent clauses, such as `WHERE`, nor in the `SELECT` itself.  The generic solution is a subquery or CTE.

Another method uses `outer apply`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hi.SKUNo [HostSKU] , SUBSTRING(vi.GTIN, 3, 14) [GTIN] ,
       c.[VendorNo] ,
       'Inv_Full_Sync' as [Reason Code] ,
       'Vendor Inventory Full Sync' as [Reason Text] ,
       c.[Quantity] , --< quantity
      'ONHAND' as  [OnHand] ,
      RTRIM(v.Category) as [Vendor Category]
FROM ItemInventory ii INNER JOIN
     HostItems hi
     ON hi.ItemId = ii.ItemId INNER JOIN
     VendorItems vi
     ON vi.ItemId = ii.ItemId AND vi.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo INNER JOIN
     Vendors v
     ON v.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo LEFTJOIN
     dbo.VendorGroups vg
     ON vg.VendorNo = v.VendorNo OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT (CASE vg.VendorGroup WHEN vg.VendorGroup THEN vg.VendorGroup
                     ELSE v.VendorNo
              END) as [VendorNo] ,
             (CASE vi.EncodeData WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1 ELSE 0
              END [Quantity]
             ) 
     ) c
WHERE QtyType = 0 AND
      c.[Quantity] > 0 --< here is where it bombs..
ORDER BY VendorNo, hi.SKUNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the column alias directly on the `WHERE`. So you either replace it with the whole `CASE` expression, or you can use a derived table or a CTE.

Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT
            hi.SKUNo [HostSKU] ,
            SUBSTRING(vi.GTIN, 3, 14) [GTIN] ,
            CASE vg.VendorGroup
              WHEN vg.VendorGroup THEN vg.VendorGroup
              ELSE v.VendorNo
            END [VendorNo] ,
            'Inv_Full_Sync' [Reason Code] ,
            'Vendor Inventory Full Sync' [Reason Text] ,
            CASE vi.EncodeData
              WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
              ELSE 0
            END [Quantity] , --< quantity
            'ONHAND' [OnHand] ,
            RTRIM(v.Category) [Vendor Category]
        FROM    ItemInventory ii
            INNER JOIN HostItems hi ON hi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
            INNER JOIN VendorItems vi ON vi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
                                         AND vi.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
            INNER JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
            LEFT JOIN dbo.VendorGroups vg ON vg.VendorNo = v.VendorNo
            WHERE QtyType = 0) X
WHERE [Quantity] > 0 --< here is where it bombs..
ORDER BY VendorNo ,
         HostSKU;
```

CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        hi.SKUNo [HostSKU] ,
        SUBSTRING(vi.GTIN, 3, 14) [GTIN] ,
        CASE vg.VendorGroup
          WHEN vg.VendorGroup THEN vg.VendorGroup
          ELSE v.VendorNo
        END [VendorNo] ,
        'Inv_Full_Sync' [Reason Code] ,
        'Vendor Inventory Full Sync' [Reason Text] ,
        CASE vi.EncodeData
          WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
          ELSE 0
        END [Quantity] , --< quantity
        'ONHAND' [OnHand] ,
        RTRIM(v.Category) [Vendor Category]
    FROM    ItemInventory ii
        INNER JOIN HostItems hi ON hi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
        INNER JOIN VendorItems vi ON vi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
                                     AND vi.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
        INNER JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
        LEFT JOIN dbo.VendorGroups vg ON vg.VendorNo = v.VendorNo
            WHERE QtyType = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE [Quantity] > 0 --< here is where it bombs..
ORDER BY VendorNo ,
         [HostSKU];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    hi.SKUNo [HostSKU] ,
    SUBSTRING(vi.GTIN, 3, 14) [GTIN] ,
    CASE vg.VendorGroup
       WHEN vg.VendorGroup THEN vg.VendorGroup
       ELSE v.VendorNo
   END [VendorNo] ,
   'Inv_Full_Sync' [Reason Code] ,
   'Vendor Inventory Full Sync' [Reason Text] ,
  CASE vi.EncodeData
     WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
     ELSE 0
  END [Quantity] , --< quantity
  'ONHAND' [OnHand] ,
  RTRIM(v.Category) [Vendor Category]
FROM    ItemInventory ii
INNER JOIN HostItems hi ON hi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
INNER JOIN VendorItems vi ON vi.ItemId = ii.ItemId
    AND vi.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
INNER JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorNo = ii.VendorNo
LEFT JOIN dbo.VendorGroups vg ON vg.VendorNo = v.VendorNo
WHERE   QtyType = 0
   CASE vi.EncodeData
      WHEN 'Y' THEN ii.Quantity1
    ELSE 0
   END > 0
ORDER BY VendorNo ,
   hi.SKUNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing this answer on the assumption that your quantity field is NULL if vi.EncodeData <> 'Y'.

In your WHERE clause you could use ISNULL or COALESCE to shortcircuit the second clause.

```
ISNULL(ii.Quantity1, 0) > 0
```

-or-

```
COALESCE(ii.Quantity1, 0) > 0
```

in the case of no quantity would equate to 0 > 0 and would exclude the row.  I'd probably stick with ISNULL though since you're only evaluating one column.